# Updating JSON Topics in Diffusion (Unified .NET Client Api)

Tags: c#, json, push, real-time, push-diffusion

I'm trying to update a JSON topic using the .NET client library of Diffusion. I know that currently there is only partial support for JSON topic in .NET but I think it is possible to update topics. So I created a topic using the Javascript client api and then update it using C#. The topic is created fine using:

```
 var initvalue = diffusion.datatypes.json().from({ "name" : "some transaction example", "price": 2.00 });
 session.topics.add("examples/rmq/testtopic", initvalue);
```

but updating it in C#:

```
updateControl.Updater.Update("examples/rmq/testtopic", "{'name': 'some other trans','price':20}", new TopicUpdaterUpdateCallback(st));
```

turns the initial value void/empty.

I am not able to find any resources with regards to JSON topics and .NET, so I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Diffusion client library for .NET has no support for JSON topics. However the upcoming version of the client library will include full JSON and binary topic support.

Update:
I am now happy to report that we released Diffusion 5.8 which includes full JSON and binary topic support. You can get the latest client libraries via [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PushTechnology.UnifiedClientInterface/5.8.0)

Comment: Not even to update? says here: http://docs.pushtechnology.com/docs/5.7.5/manual/html/designguide/data/topics/json_topics.html

The .NET Unified API, C Unified API, and Apple® Unified API have limited support for JSON topics. These APIs can subscribe to, fetch from, and update JSON topics through the Content API.

Comment: This seems to be a mistake in our documentation. I apologise for that. As it stands now the .NET client library doesn't support JSON. But as I mentioned in my original answer we will have full JSON and binary topic support very soon.